# nginx doesn't find the directory but apache does

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, root, documentroot

I use apache as the backend server and nginx on the frontend. Apache listens to port 8080 and nginx to port 80. What I do is have the root point to the public folder foreach virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName site.com
        ServerAlias site.com *.site.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site.com/public
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/site.com/public/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And here's the nginx config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        access_log /var/log/nginx.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx.error.log;
        root /var/www/site.com/public;
        index index.php index.html;
        server_name site.com *.site.com;
        location / {
    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_cache one;
            proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header updating;
            proxy_cache_key $scheme$host$request_uri;
            proxy_cache_valid       200 301 302 20m;
            proxy_cache_valid       404 1m;
            proxy_cache_valid       any 15m;
    }
        }
        location ~ /\.(ht|git) {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

The problem is Apache resolves the domain just fine `(site.com:8080)`, but nginx shows instead a **502 Bad Gateway** `(site.com:80)`. I tried looking at the error_log and access_log but I can't find any hint for **why  can't nginx work**.

**EDIT:** The problem was I wasn't able to include that isolated config for nginx.

Comment: Nothing looks wrong, and you decided not to include the log so it's hard to help...

Comment: bad gateway suggests that you proxy_pass (or fastcgi_pass etc). Where's that piece of config?

Comment: the log is empty :(

Comment: @3molo hi thanks, I just included it.

Comment: Is apache listening to your non localhost ip, or to all ips? (if all ips, are there any firewall rules?)

Comment: @3molo  I didn't install any firewall, and Apache is set as `Listen 8080`

Comment: jack spariow: 'netstat -avn|grep 8080'

Comment: @3molo sigh, I forgot to include that nginx config :)

Comment: So this is solved?

Answer (score 0):

What user is nginx running as? It's possible that the user under which nginx is running cannot access the folder in question.

Comment: I only chowned it to: `chown -R apache:apache /var/www/site.com`. How will I know what user nginx is running as? I only run them through ssh root access.

Comment: Check the nginx config file. It should be in /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
The Apache config file has a similar parameter. By default, Apache runs as the "apache" user.

Comment: It's obviously related to him proxying the requests, not permissions.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if I'm wrong, but I contend that it's not obviously a proxy issue.

Comment: I'm 99% certain that you would only get a bad gateway if a backend is down. prove me wrong and I'll remove my -1 :)

Comment: Well, I'm only disagreeing with the "obviously" part of your statement. If it ends up being a proxy issue, that wouldn't surprise me one bit. However, I've had this exact problem before, and it turned out to be a permissions issue.